# SSRS Expression for color error

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I've got this expression for my percent column to work out which colour to use based on several column values in my SSRS report.

```
=IIF(Fields!GrossMarginActual.Value = 0 AND Fields!GrossMarginPercentageActual.Value = 0, 0, Fields!VarianceGrossMargin.Value) AND
IIF(Round(Fields!VarianceGrossMargin.Value,2) < 0.00, "Red", "Black")
```

However I get the following

> The color expression for the text run 'VarianceGrossMarginPercent.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30205] End of Statement Expected.

I am guessing my syntax on my expression isn't quite right. I've wrapped extra brackets round it but that just gives me back errors. This correct syntax doesn't flag up any errors in the expression box.

Would appreciate a second pair of eyes to look over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF((Fields!GrossMarginActual.Value = 0 AND Fields!GrossMarginPercentageActual.Value = 0, "Red",
IIF(Round(Fields!VarianceGrossMargin.Value,2) < 0.00, "Red", "Black")))
```

Comment: Cheers, Just gave it a go I got a red line error in the expression box after the comma after the zero here:
Fields!GrossMarginPercentageActual.Value = 0, 
The error is the same when I run the report but this time it's saying it's expecting an ')'

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to add the missing bracket and got it working. 

`=IIF((Fields!GrossMarginActual.Value = 0 AND Fields!GrossMarginPercentageActual.Value = 0), "Red",
IIF(Round(Fields!VarianceGrossMargin.Value,2) < 0.00, "Red", "Black"))`

Is what I did for the final expression and that worked!

Comment: That's great! Sorry for that missing parenthesis. Glad I helped at least.